How to cancel a NSBatchInsertRequest midway?
The user of my app can import in the ranges of 10k audio files.
An AudioFile entity is unique as long as BOTH its name and file extension are unique. I have already added "name,fileExtension" as the constraint in the xcdatamodeld file.
During the import, the user can cancel the import using a cancel button or could kill the app from app switcher and since NSBatchInsertRequest saves directly to disk, bypassing memory, how do I revert the changes or remove the managed objects that were already saved to disk?
func createNewBackgroundContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let taskContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
        taskContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        return taskContext
    }

func importFiles(from urls: [URL]) async {
        let importContext = DataController.shared.createNewBackgroundContext()
        
        var objects: [[String: Any]] = []
        
        for url in urls {
            if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                let metadata = getMetadata(url: url)
                
                let audioFileName = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent                  
                let fileExtension = url.pathExtension
                let artist = metadata?.value(forKey: "artist") as? String ?? "Unknown Artist"
                let album = metadata?.value(forKey: "album") as? String ?? "Unknown Album"
                let genre = metadata?.value(forKey: "genre") as? String ?? "Unknown Genre"
                let composer = metadata?.value(forKey: "composer") as? String ?? "Unknown Composer"
                let year = metadata?.value(forKey: "year") as? String ?? "Unknown Release Year"
                let importDate = Date()
                let artwork = audioFileName + ".\(fileExtension)"
                let trackNumber = metadata?.value(forKey: "trackNumber") as? Int ?? -1
                
                let properties: [String: Any] = [
                    "name": audioFileName,
                    "artist": artist,
                    "album": album,
                    "genre": genre,
                    "year": year,
                    "composer": composer,
                    "importDate": importDate,
                    "trackNumber": trackNumber,
                    "artwork": artwork,
                    "fileExtension": fileExtension,
                    "favourite": false
                ]
                objects.append(properties)

//Save the file to disk
                save(url: url, with: audioFileName + ".\(fileExtension)")
            }
            
            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
             
        await importContext.perform {
            let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: AudioFile.entity(), objects: objects)
             
            if let fetchResult = try? importContext.execute(batchInsertRequest),
               let batchInsertResult = fetchResult as? NSBatchInsertResult,
               let success = batchInsertResult.result as? Bool, success {
                return
            }
        }
}


What exactly is it you need to handle if the app is killed by the user, I would have thought that nothing got persisted in such situation?

wont unnecessary audio file entities be stored should the user cancel the operation?

That’s not what I asked about but I guess from your response that you haven’t done any research yourself. Why don’t you try to kill the app or press the cancel button and see what happens? Maybe this is not an issue at all. My assumption is that the batch insert only performs one save at the end so it’s all or nothing.

After testing (the documentation wasn't clear at all), yes your assumption was right.
To answer your first question, in the for loop, going over each url, I save the file to disk during each iteration. Since the batch insert only performs a save at the end, when the user kills the app during the for loop, there will be a consistency issue since the files would be saved to disk but the audio file entity itself would not be saved in core data. Thus, there would be more files on disk than the corresponding entities in core data.

Since the value won't be in CoreData but the file will be there, from times to times, maybe check the count of files and the count of entities (or something like that), and delete all the files that aren't listed in CoreData if necessary. Since it might be a heavy procedure, you might want to add a button to "clean" for that.

Is there a better way to do this automatically without an additional button?

You could do it in background at each app launch...

I was focusing on the batch insert before and not so much on the files but I assume you also want to remove all the files if the import was interrupted and also what takes the most time here is saving the files to disk and not the batch insert?

I am not sure if removing the files is the way to go. How about storing the dictionary straight to core data using batch insert for each loop iterations when going over the URLs? Is that efficient?

Cast result to NSPersistentStoreAsynchronousResult. It have cancel
